# Using a Microsoft Kinect on a PC as a Webcam; Is \Stream.sys for Kinect Available?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, webcam, kinect, windows-hello

I am in need of your help getting a Microsoft Kinect (Xbox One model, which I don't even this is worth mentioning as I have had the conversion kit from the Microsoft Store working like a charm.to function as a webcam on Windows 10≥.586.164

### Ψ

**I know a Microsoft Kinect is** many things in a slick package with two units being *a color webcam on a microphone array**.

The USB 3 bandwidth is there, but I can only ever get my Kinect to function as a webcam when I sign in using the fantastic Windows Hello (I hate passwords).

---

Example webcam failure: My dog doesn't seem to grow change in appearance, so let's go with something new, like old mug.[image: Choco-chan]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL2tC.png)

[image: Kinect fails to be a valid webcam in Windows 10.586.16]
It tries to be helpful [by instructing the use to make sure their audio or video device](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/fix-windows-camera-app-problems-with-pc-cameras) as listed in**Device Manager** has got a someone on that like named Stream.sys.

---

I must be missing it, don't know which version I'd need, an don't trust bein about to locate it from a safe place (one that signs it with Microsoft Corporation). Maybe I should try copying `KinectSensor.sys` to `System.` but I'm guessing there are quite a few sensors handled by driver.

## Kinect Sensor drivers (WDF INTERFACE 0)

[image: WDF KiNectSensor Interface 0 missing Stream.sys driver file for webcamera use.]

The drivers for my **Knicked which appear in Audio inputs andouts** an under **Sound, video and game controllers**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has drivers to let the Kinect do this in a different update channel. Here's how to get those drivers from Windows Update.

### Opt-in to receive test distribution drivers

1. Open the Windows Registry Editor (regedit.exe).
2. Go to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\
3. Create subkeys \DriverFlighting\Partner\
4. Under \Partner subkey, create a string named “TargetRing” and key-in “Drivers” as the value.

### Get the drivers from Device Manager or Windows Update

From Device Manager:

1. Open Device Manager (Windows key + x, then m).
2. Expand “Kinect sensor devices”.
3. Right-click on "WDF KinectSensor Interface 0".
4. Click "Update Driver Software..."
5. Click “Search automatically for updated driver software”.
6. Allow it to download and install the new driver.
7. Reboot.

You can now use the Kinect for Xbox One as a webcam and for Windows Hello.

References:

- [Windows Hello with the Kinect v2](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Windows-Hello-with-the-Kinect-v2)
- [Test Distribution Drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt149093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I'm Brazilian and I don't know much English.

"(I found a solution... Lots of people have had the Kinect restart bug and I have located the issue.

Head here... C:\Windows\System32\Kinect Rename KinectMonitor.exe to KinectMonitor.bak Rename KincetService.exe to KinectMonitor.exe

This has thus far worked for me every single time no matter what USB hub was in use.

Let me know how you get on?)" and it didn't work, I get a red "X" in "Verifi Kinect Software Installed" and "Verify Kinect Depth and Color Streams" and two yellow "!" in "Update Configuration Definitions" and " "USB Controller" nothing lights up on it and the webcam does not generate an image.

In the original it has a red "X" in "Verify Kinect Depth and Color Streams" and two "!" yellow in "Update Configuration Definitions" and ""USB Controller" nothing lights up on it and the webcam does not generate an image.

I used the Kinect V2 as a webcam and after some update it started to freeze the image and I went to do a procedure using "KinectCam.ax", "KINECTSQM.DLL".... (cd ""

c:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe KinectCam.ax) and after that it didn't work anymore and I don't know how to revert it.

There is the "3D Scan" application that worked really well and now it opens, tries to locate the Kinect V2 and closes by itself.

I am using Windos 10 Enterprise 22H2 Build 19045.3758 and Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0

My PC is a Ryzen 9 5900X with MSI MPG X570 Gaming Plus card, 32Gb of RAM, RTX 3080 ti 12Gb Eagle, I have an Orico HUB with 16 USB 3.0 ports.

Eu sou brasileiro e não sei muito inglês.

Teitei esse procedimento "(I found a solution... Lots of people have had the Kinect restart bug and I have located the issue.

Head here... C:\Windows\System32\Kinect Rename KinectMonitor.exe to KinectMonitor.bak Rename KincetService.exe to KinectMonitor.exe

This has thus far worked for me every single time no matter what USB hub was in use.

Let me know how you get on?)" e não deu certo, eu fico com um "X" vermelho em "Verifi Kinect Software Installed" e em "Verify Kinect Depth and Color Streams" e dois com "!" amarala em "Update Configuration Definitions" e " "USB Controller" não acende nada nele e a webcam não gera imagem.

No original ele fica com um "X" vermelho em  "Verify Kinect Depth and Color Streams"  e dois com "!" amarala em "Update Configuration Definitions" e " "USB Controller" não acende nada nele e a webcam não gera imagem.

Eu usava o Kinect V2 como webcam e apos alguma atualização ela pasava a travar a imagem e eu fui fazer um procedimento usando o "KinectCam.ax", "KINECTSQM.DLL".... (cd ""

c:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe KinectCam.ax) e depois disso não funcionou mais e não sei como reverter.

Há o aplicativo "3D Scan" que funcionava super bem e agora ele abre, fica tentando localizar o Kinect V2 e fecha sozinho.

Estou usando o Windos 10 Enterprise 22H2 Compilação 19045.3758 e Experiência  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0

Meu PC é um Ryzen 9 5900X com placa MSI MPG X570 Gaming Plus, 32Gb de RAM, RTX 3080 ti 12Gb Eagle, tenho Um HUB Orico de 16 portas USB 3.0.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answers are expected to be written in English. Preferably written to a degree which has little to no grammatical errors considering the amount of tools that exist that assist with that goal